# In Azure AD, how to set and read a user's primary email through PowerShell (e.g. Set-AzureADUser and Get-AzureADUser)?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I have a user in Azure AD. Under "Authentication methods", this user's "primary" email is set to some value. All other fields for Authentication Contact Info (e.g. Phone, Alternate Phone, and Alternate Email) are blank. 
[image]

I'm looking at Microsoft public documentation regarding the PowerShell cmdlets Set-AzureADUser and Get-AzureADUser:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata

This documentation mentions how to set alternate emails, but makes no mention of how to set the user's primary email.

Additionally, the PowerShell cmdlet Get-AzureADUser does not seem to return the user's primary email ([screenshot here](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/mailfieldempty.png)), even though the primary email is clearly set when viewing the user in the Azure portal.
[image]

So, **how can I set and read the primary email of a user in Azure AD programmatically**?

Comment: If Mail is blank, does ProxyAddresses contain an `SMTP:` value?

Comment: ProxyAddresses looks empty to me. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/nNLloDw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a user's authentication email is now possible via the Microsoft Graph beta API. See [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/manage-your-authentication-phone-numbers-and-more-in-new/ba-p/1257359) for details.

Currently this can only be done via delegated permissions in your Azure AD Application. So a user has to authenticate before making any updates.

Below is some rough sample code using PowerShell. Note that most of it pertains to obtaining the access token. Only the last 3 lines are relevant to adding an authentication email to the user.

```
$AzureTenantId = <YourTenantId>
$AzureAppId = <YourAzureADApplicationId> #The application needs to have appropiate delagated permissions set
$UserName = 'exampleuser@test.com'
$UserAuthEmail = 'exampleuser@gmail.com'

#Get token by getting user to authenticate with a device code
$Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"

$DeviceCodeRequestParams = @{
    Method = 'POST'
    Uri    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$AzureTenantId/oauth2/devicecode"
    Body   = @{
        client_id = $AzureAppId
        resource  = $Resource
    }
}
$DeviceCodeRequest = Invoke-RestMethod @DeviceCodeRequestParams

Write-Host "A browser window will launch in 5 seconds. Enter the code $($DeviceCodeRequest.user_code) to authenticate. You should just be able to paste it." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Set-Clipboard $DeviceCodeRequest.user_code
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Start $DeviceCodeRequest.verification_url

Pause

$TokenRequestParams = @{
    Method = 'POST'
    Uri    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$AzureTenantId/oauth2/token"
    Body   = @{
        grant_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
        code       = $DeviceCodeRequest.device_code
        client_id  = $AzureAppId
    }
}
$TokenRequest = Invoke-RestMethod @TokenRequestParams
$Token = $TokenRequest.access_token

#Set the email authentication
$Headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $Token"}
$BodyJson = "{`"emailAddress`": `"$UserAuthEmail`"}"
Invoke-RestMethod "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/$UserName/authentication/emailMethods" -Method POST -ContentType application/json -Headers $Headers -Body $BodyJson
```

Answer (score 1):

From screenshot, this user looks like a synced user in a hybrid setup with no mailbox.

If user had a mailbox the primary address will be populated, since no address i assume user does not have a mailbox.

If its a sync user then you will need to update information on Local AD and let it sync to Azure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to clarify that the context of setting a user's "primary" email is in the context of self-service password reset (SSPR). So this email cannot be "your primary work or school email". [Screenshot](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/set-mail.png).

So the idea would be to set an email such as an @gmail.com for SSPR. Is there any way of doing this programmatically? We're not trying to modify the user's **actual** on-premises or Office 365 mailbox.

Comment: Whether the user proxyaddress, primary address or othermails is set if SSPR is turned on user will be prompted to set recovery method on next logon.  Email used for SSPR is **NOT** visible through any ADD powershell command that i know even though thus [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata#set-the-authentication-data-with-powershell-version-2) said so. [proof](https://i.imgur.com/a5eRbSF.png)

Comment: You can set an email under the [authentication methods](https://i.imgur.com/WKtQ2s8.png) section in AAD but user will still need to [verify address](https://i.imgur.com/DXEB1wP.png).

Answer (score 1):

The authentication email field and the authentication phone are not settable in PowerShell as of yet.

More details in this MSDN forums post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52c9b994-a41f-4072-8974-cbccd699dbd3/set-and-read-primary-email-through-powershell-getazureaduser?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: This reference link is nearly 3 years old.